Copy/paste meeting notes for google docs
For our meeting notes we usually copy/paste something like
---
@today - XYZ meeting notes

AIs
- Example AI

Notes
- Example note
---

So the doc will look like that section followed by
8/6 - XYZ meeting notes

AIs
- Foo the bar

Notes
- John wants to try a new bread
---
7/25 - XYZ meeting notes

AIs
- Bar the foo

Notes
- Jane thinks we should add more foos

Is there a way to automate this within Google Docs? Would be helpful to have a single button to place that without needing people to play with the formatting when trying to paste a big section of text and tables. Especially since it means we have to go low-tech with our formatting at risk of making it hard to copy/paste.
Open to addons, apps script, though ideally it's a native solution.

You can create meeting notes using the "Meeting notes" building blocks
https://blog.google/products/workspace/google-docs-meeting-notes/
Either:

Insert > Templates > Meeting notes

Enter @ anywhere in the document to bring up the search menu, then select "Meeting notes" under "Building Blocks"



This will pre-populate something that looks like below. Note that you can use either approach in an existing document, so you can insert meeting notes to the top of the file each meeting and it will add this template above your notes from earlier meetings (image source)

